# Cross-compile code for ARM builds, but wont run

Tags: arm, qemu

I have Eclipse CDT and Linaro 7.3.1 installed according to [this page](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black) on my Ubuntu machine.  Then, I install some other tools like QEMU and the different architectures for ARM after [this guide](http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter7/).  Next, I follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9yFyWsyyGk&t=1060s) to start a Hello World code.

The code builds without problem.  However, it fails to run and complains:

```
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
```

I already link to the folder containing this file.  Why is it giving this error?  The video mentions that QEMU takes care of the problem.  It doesnt seem to work for me.  Please help.

---

Turns out to be a linking problem.  Fixed.

Comment: Did you installed the `libc6-armhf-cross` package ?

Comment: @jeremf, thank you so much.  It turned out to be a linking problem.  I had it fixed.